# MySQL - procedure, cursor, inner join

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, sql-update, cursor, inner-join

So, I have a table that updates patients' statuses according to their latest submission of information. At the end of every day, I check whether the patients have completed their treatment that day or not, and based on those results, I fill out a table that then sends out emails to either the patients (if they are following the treatment), or their caregivers (if they are not).

Before we included emails for the caregivers, I was using a daily stored procedure that calculated participation, and a join query to put together the relevant messages. It looked like this:

```
 DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE DEFINER=CURRENT_USER PROCEDURE `proc_day_calc`()
    NO SQL
    COMMENT 'calculates days and fills table with messages (tbl_to_mail)'
BEGIN

    UPDATE `tbl_patient_status` SET d0 = d0 + 1, updated_by = 'd0count', checked = 1;

    UPDATE `tbl_patient_status` SET 
        d1 = d1 + 1, 
        d4 = d4 + 1, 
        patient_status = 'seguimiento',
        updated_by = 'proc_day_calc.seg', 
        checked = 2 
    WHERE checked = 1 AND latest_submit >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;

    UPDATE `tbl_patient_status` SET 
        d2 = d2 + 1,
        d4 = 0,
        patient_status = 'contingencia', 
        updated_by = 'proc_day_calc.cont',
        checked = 2
    WHERE checked = 1 AND latest_submit < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;

    UPDATE `tbl_patient_status` SET 
        d3 = d3 + 1,
        patient_status = 'post',
        updated_by = 'd0count',
        checked = 2
    WHERE d1 >= 22 AND patient_status = 'cierre';

    UPDATE `tbl_patient_status` SET 
        patient_status = 'drop-out',
        updated_by = 'proc_day_calc'
    WHERE latest_submit < NOW() - INTERVAL 10 DAY AND checked = 1 AND patient_status = 'contingencia';

    INSERT INTO tbl_to_mail (to_email, subject, body)
        SELECT DISTINCT id_user, subject, body FROM tbl_patient_status INNER JOIN lst_msg_treatmnt USING (`patient_status`, `language`, `role`) WHERE tbl_patient_status.checked = 2 AND tbl_patient_status.d1 = lst_msg_treatmnt.on_d1 OR tbl_patient_status.d2 = lst_msg_treatmnt.on_d2 OR tbl_patient_status.d3 = lst_msg_treatmnt.on_d3 OR tbl_patient_status.d4 = lst_msg_treatmnt.on_d4;
    UPDATE `tbl_patient_status` SET checked = 3;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

** I was working on fixing the glitch of updating ALL rows to 3, instead of only the ones who got the messages, but it wasn't a big deal because every new input by the patients sets checked = 0, and then the day (d0) sets it back to 1, so the checks are basically a gauge for me to know whether the process is running smoothly or not.

Now, we needed to add the caregivers, and CONCAT their emails into one field (to reduce the number of emails sent), I tried introducing a cursor to make the procedure more precise by performing line by line calculations (I will later have to add even more calculations to each row), but the cursor stops after the first UPDATE (d0count). If I remove that UPDATE query, though, then it only completes the first IF statement or CASE (tried both), and shuts down after that without going to the rows that fall under other cases:

```
DROP PROCEDURE `proc_day_calc`;
CREATE DEFINER=CURRENT_patient PROCEDURE `proc_day_calc`() NOT DETERMINISTIC NO SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER BEGIN

    DECLARE checked INT;
    DECLARE latest_submit DATETIME;
    DECLARE patient_status TEXT;
    DECLARE row_not_found TINYINT DEFAULT FALSE;

    DECLARE cursor_patientstatus CURSOR FOR SELECT checked, latest_submit, patient_status FROM `tbl_patient_status` WHERE checked = 1;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND 
        SET row_not_found = TRUE;

    UPDATE tbl_patient_status SET d0 = d0 + 1, updated_by = 'd0count', checked = 1;

    OPEN cursor_patientstatus;

    WHILE row_not_found = FALSE DO 

        FETCH cursor_patientstatus INTO checked, latest_submit, patient_status;

        IF checked = 1 AND latest_submit >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY THEN

            UPDATE `tbl_patient_status` SET 
                d1 = d1 + 1, 
                d4 = d4 + 1, 
                patient_status = 'seguimiento',
                updated_by = 'proc_day_calc.seg', 
                checked = 2;

            ### INSERTS MESSAGES TO SEND ONLY FOR patientS (NO MESSAGES FOR CAREGIVERS ON SEGUIMIENTO)
            INSERT INTO tbl_to_mail (role, id_patient, username, to_mail, subject, body, added_by)
                SELECT DISTINCT lst_msg_treatmnt.role, tbl_profile_patient.id_patient, tbl_profile_patient.username, tbl_profile_patient.email, lst_msg_treatmnt.subject, lst_msg_treatmnt.body, 'proc_day_calc.seg'
                FROM tbl_patient_status
                INNER JOIN lst_msg_treatmnt
                INNER JOIN tbl_profile_patient
                ON tbl_patient_status.id_patient = tbl_profile_patient.id_patient AND tbl_profile_patient.language = lst_msg_treatmnt.language AND tbl_patient_status.d1 = lst_msg_treatmnt.on_d1 OR tbl_patient_status.d4 = lst_msg_treatmnt.on_d4
            WHERE lst_msg_treatmnt.role = 'patient' AND lst_msg_treatmnt.patient_status = 'seguimiento' AND tbl_patient_status.checked = 2;

            UPDATE `tbl_patient_status` SET checked = 3;

        ELSEIF checked = 1 AND latest_submit < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY THEN
            UPDATE `tbl_patient_status` SET 
                    d2 = d2 + 1,
                    d4 = 0,
                    patient_status = 'contingencia', 
                    updated_by = 'proc_day_calc.cont',
                    checked = 2;

            ### INSERTS MESSAGES TO SEND - ONE INNER JOIN PER TABLE (patient)
            INSERT INTO tbl_to_mail (role, id_patient, username, to_mail, subject, body, added_by)
                SELECT DISTINCT 'patient', tbl_profile_patient.id_patient, tbl_profile_patient.username, tbl_profile_patient.email, lst_msg_treatmnt.subject, lst_msg_treatmnt.body, 'proc_day_calc.cont'
                FROM tbl_patient_status
                INNER JOIN lst_msg_treatmnt
                INNER JOIN tbl_profile_patient
                ON tbl_patient_status.id_patient = tbl_profile_patient.id_patient AND tbl_profile_patient.language = lst_msg_treatmnt.language AND tbl_patient_status.d2 = lst_msg_treatmnt.on_d2
            WHERE lst_msg_treatmnt.role = 'patient' AND lst_msg_treatmnt.patient_status = 'contingencia' AND tbl_patient_status.checked = 2;


            ### INSERTS MESSAGES TO SEND - ONE INNER JOIN PER TABLE (CAREGIVERS)
            INSERT INTO tbl_to_mail (role, id_patient, username, to_mail, subject, body, added_by)
                SELECT DISTINCT lst_msg_treatmnt.role, tbl_profile_caregiver.id_patient, NULL,  GROUP_CONCAT(tbl_profile_caregiver.email), lst_msg_treatmnt.subject, lst_msg_treatmnt.body, 'proc_day_calc.cont'
                FROM tbl_patient_status
                INNER JOIN lst_msg_treatmnt
                INNER JOIN tbl_profile_caregiver
                ON tbl_patient_status.id_patient = tbl_profile_caregiver.id_patient AND tbl_profile_caregiver.language = lst_msg_treatmnt.language AND tbl_patient_status.d2 = lst_msg_treatmnt.on_d2
                WHERE lst_msg_treatmnt.patient_status = 'contingencia' AND lst_msg_treatmnt.role = 'caregiver' AND  tbl_patient_status.checked = 2;

            UPDATE `tbl_patient_status` SET checked = 3;

        ### CIERRE doesn't send messages because TF_Day_21 activates Apiant on its own, but it doesn't send messages for CAREGIVERS!!! COME FIX 
        ELSEIF checked = 1 AND patient_status = 'cierre' THEN
            UPDATE `tbl_patient_status` SET 
                    d3 = d3 + 1,
                    patient_status = 'post',
                    updated_by = 'proc_day_calc.post',
                    checked = 2;

        ELSEIF latest_submit < NOW() - INTERVAL 10 DAY AND checked = 1 AND patient_status = 'contingencia' THEN
            UPDATE `tbl_patient_status` SET 
                patient_status = 'drop-out',
                updated_by = 'proc_day_calc.drop',
                checked = 2;
        END IF;
    END WHILE;

    CLOSE cursor_patientstatus;


END
```

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated! In the meantime, I'm patching it by running two separate procedures. The first to count the days, and the second to prepare the messages. Can I make it all run smoothly in one process? Or what would be the most efficient and precise way to run these kind of calculations.

Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I also tried changing the names of the cursor variables to letters (a,b,c), but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Among potentially other issues, `WHILE row_not_found = FALSE DO` is invalid, because it always allows the loop to iterate one more time than it should.  You need to `my_loop:` `LOOP` then `FETCH ...` then **immediately** test `row_not_found` and `LEAVE my_loop` if true.  And yes, your program variable names absolutely **must** be different than any column names in any referenced tables.

Comment: Also, why do multiple instances of `UPDATE \`tbl_patient_status\` ...` inside the loop have no `WHERE` clause?  That seems incorrect.  The position of the cursor does not impact any statements inside the loop.  These would update all rows.

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot, in answer to your question, they don't have where clauses because the IF conditions already filtered the data, but I'm going to try adding them, do you think that's what causing the loop not to run? or maybe the case not to be fulfilled?